# Can you hide/render tabs in primefaces using wizard

Tags: java, primefaces

Is it possible to render different tabs using the primeface's p:Wizard? I know you can skip tabs, but I need to have a tab rendered conditionally based on information entered in tab 1 (A). If the user enters in a specific set of check boxes, I need tab C to be rendered and part of the flow, and not shown otherwise.

the skeleton of my xhtml

```
<p:wizard id="FlowWiz" flowListener="#{myBean.handleFlow}"> 
    <p:tab id="A" title="A">
        stuff
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab id="B" title="B">
        stuff
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab id="C" title="C">
        <ccpath:extraDetailsxml isWizard = "true" />
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab id="D" title="D">
        stuff
    </p:tab>
</p:wizard>
```

The skeleton of my bean

```
public class myBean() { 
    private String step = "A";

    public String handleFlow(FlowEvent event){
        isAccepted = false;
    
        if(validatestuff()){
            if(event.getNewStep().equals("B") && showTab()) 
               primeFaces.ajax().update("pathTo:flowWiz");
        
            setStep(event.getNewStep());
        
            return event.getNewStep();
        }else{
            return event.getOldStep();
        }     
    }
}
```

The data to render tab C will be entered in A, so id like to have tab C rendered when "Next" is clicked. this is what my current xhtml and bean looked like (kinda). any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

**my.xhtml**

```
<p:tab id="C" title="C" rendered="#{myBean.showTab}">
```

**myBean**

```
public boolean showTab() {
    boolean rendered = true;
    if (){
     //some logic
     rendered = false;
    }
    return rendered;
}
```

I haven't tested it with *<p:wizard>*, but I think it should work.